# Saving data to file while running android junit test in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit

I am running Android JUnit tests in Eclipse. I have a function which is tested during the JUnit run. Inside the function i save some value to a local file. But it seems it is not being saved. What is the reason, and also how can I output some data in the console from that function?

It is basically the same unit testing code from the sample application provided by robotium developers.

```
public void testDisplayBlackBox() {
        //Enter any integer/decimal value for first editfield, we are writing 10
        solo.enterText(0, "10");
        //Enter any interger/decimal value for first editfield, we are writing 20
        solo.enterText(1, "20");
        //Click on Multiply button
        solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");
        //Verify that resultant of 10 x 20
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("200"));
        ArrayList <View> aview= solo.getCurrentViews();
        for (View v:aview)
        {
            //System.out.println(v.toString());
            //solo.enterText(0, v.toString());
            try {
                FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("test.txt"), v.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //FileUtils 
        }
        //aview.get(0).
    }
```

Comment: @subodh any solutions? i do not see any.

Comment: can you please post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot save files locally during test execution. You can save it on for instance sd-card, and then you can pull it through adb (more help here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html):

```
public void testDisplayBlackBox() {
    //Enter any integer/decimal value for first editfield, we are writing 10
    solo.enterText(0, "10");
    //Enter any interger/decimal value for first editfield, we are writing 20
    solo.enterText(1, "20");
    //Click on Multiply button
    solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");
    //Verify that resultant of 10 x 20
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("200"));
    ArrayList <View> aview= solo.getCurrentViews();
    StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
    for (View v:aview)
    {           
        sB.append(v.toString());
    }
    saveToFile(sB.toString())
}


public void saveToFile(String text) {
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(path, test.txt);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] data = text.getBytes();
        fos.write(data);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For debugging you can use android.util.Log:

```
Log.d("TEST", "text");
```